# How to initialize AWS XRay for all lambdas in a NodeJS serverless project

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, aws-xray

As I understand, XRay has to be initialized before every AWS clients, and http clients if I want to also trace outgoing http requests. This is the code for XRay initialization.

```
import aws from 'aws-sdk'
import AWSXRay from 'aws-xray-sdk'
import http from 'http'
import https from 'https'

AWSXRay.captureHTTPsGlobal(http)
AWSXRay.captureHTTPsGlobal(https)
AWSXRay.capturePromise()
AWSXRay.captureAWS(aws)
```

It seems easy for a single lambda. However, I have a NodeJS serverless project which has a bunch of lambdas, and many more will be added soon. I'm finding a solution that meets

- No code duplicate for the initialization
- The initialization is done more or less automatically for developers. I don't want the developers to manually initialize xray during development

I'm thinking about a module, named 'xray-initialization.ts', and hopefully inject `import './xray-initialization'` into a lambda handler with a build tool. Is it feasible?